# Google Cloud Storage with gspythonlibrary

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have to write a python script with which I should be able list other protected buckets owned by other people who are ready grand access. For this I created a project and enabled Google Cloud Storage in my Google API console, then I installed gsutil and stored 'my credentials' in '.boto' file. now I have to list metadata of all buckets where I have access. My question is what I or other buckets owners has to do to grant access to me/my project so that my script can list metadata of all buckets/object inside bucket?

I'm following this doc for python scripting: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary

Answer (score 2):

You can only list all buckets you have access to within a project.

There is no way to list all buckets which you might have access to. The list of buckets you have access to would be extremely large, because it would include all buckets marked as public.

I would suggest you have people who give you access to their buckets give you their bucket name explicitly.